# Simple systemd service to lift kernel lockdown - permission denied

Tags: kernel, permissions, systemd

So, I have spent a long time trying to fix a simple `systemd` service which can lift the kernel lockdown. After a lot of time spent researching and googling I couldn't find an answer to my question.

What I want is a script to run before an existing service called `nbfc.service` is run. I tried to do this by making a new service which calls this script before `nbfc.service` is called. My service file looks like this `/etc/systemd/system/lift-kernel-lockdown.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable kernel lockdown feature
Before=nbfc.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/lift_kernel_lockdown.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script I wrote looks like this /opt/lift_kernel_lockdown.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

DEFAULT_SYSRQ=$(sysctl -n kernel.sysrq)
sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1
echo x > /proc/sysrq-trigger


sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=${DEFAULT_SYSRQ}
```

When I run the following command:

```
systemctl start lift-kernel-lockdown.service
```

I get the following output:

```
Job for lift-kernel-lockdown.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status lift-kernel-lockdown.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After this, I run the command:

```
systemctl status lift-kernel-lockdown.service
```

and I get the following output:

```
lift-kernel-lockdown.service - Disable kernel lockdown feature
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/lift-kernel-lockdown.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-04-06 23:48:03 CEST; 2min 34s ago
  Process: 5459 ExecStart=/opt/lift_kernel_lockdown.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 5459 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: Starting Disable kernel lockdown feature...
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[5459]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[5459]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/lift_kernel_lockdown.sh: Permission denied
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: Failed to start Disable kernel lockdown feature.
```

When I run the command:

```
journalctl -xe
```

I get the output:

```
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           _init/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:503:13
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop gnome-shell[1495]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this._currentWindow is null
                                           _setCurrentRect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:536:13
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           _init/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:503:13
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop gnome-shell[1495]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this._currentWindow is null
                                           _setCurrentRect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:536:13
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           _init/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:503:13
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop polkitd(authority=local)[876]: Operator of unix-session:2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:david to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-u
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: Starting Disable kernel lockdown feature...
-- Subject: Unit lift-kernel-lockdown.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit lift-kernel-lockdown.service has begun starting up.
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[5459]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[5459]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/lift_kernel_lockdown.sh: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /opt/lift_kernel_lockdown.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The process /opt/lift_kernel_lockdown.sh could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is 13.
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop gnome-shell[1495]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: activate: Error: Error invoking IBus.set_global_engine_async: Expected function for callback argument callback, got u
                                           setEngine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:207:9
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           activateInputSource@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:490:13
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27
                                           activate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:65:9
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           _inputSourcesChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:620:13
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           reload@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:369:9
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           _ibusSetContentType@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:691:9
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                           _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27
                                           _setContentType@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:183:9
                                           wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: lift-kernel-lockdown.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop systemd[1]: Failed to start Disable kernel lockdown feature.
-- Subject: Unit lift-kernel-lockdown.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit lift-kernel-lockdown.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
apr 06 23:48:03 davetop polkitd(authority=local)[876]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5450:312328 (system bus name :1.439, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, 
lines 2683-2736/2736 (END)
```

I truly have no idea where to go from here or how to solve it, I would truly appreciate the help from someone with knowledge about this.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to `/proc/sysrq-trigger` won't work due to the restriction.Press Alt-Sysrq-x on an attached keyboard.